# Calculating weighted monthly average from daily values, including missing data

Tags: excel

I have a list of price changes for a product over many years, with associated dates of changes in the price down to the day. However, these prices change infrequently, meaning I may have only 4 data points in one year. *What is most important is that in between these price change points, prices remain constant from the last reported point, even though they are not listed in the data.*

How do I find the weighted monthly average, accounting for the days in which data is not shown?

[image: Excel data]

The average for `Item3` in January 2015, for example, should end up a weighted average of 21 days of prices at 110, 7 days of prices at 94 and 3 days of prices at 88, averaged over the 31 days of January. This is therefore 104.26

I've tried using the suggested formula in a [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769790/calculate-monthly-average-from-daily-data-without-pivottable), but what that does is simply take the average of values listed in January 2015, for example. That gives the answer of 97.33 instead of what should be 104.26

The final output table should be a time series table, starting with January to December for every year. **For example**:

[Ideal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gs4g.png)

Comment: It would be quite easy if 'helper columns' are allowed (a column with every day - which you'd hide). But a direct formula with the results at once is quite difficult, as you dont have each month at least once and several multiple time. Would the helper columns be a viable option for you ?

Comment: Btw, the october 2011 average on your 'ideal output' is wrong, should be 144 (or 143.77) :)

Comment: Indeed, a helper column could be implemented, although ideally a direct formula could be applied. The ideal output was an example using a previously wrong formula :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array formula solution would look like this:

```
=AVERAGE(
      IF((ROW(INDEX($A:$A,MIN($B$3:$B$20)):INDEX($A:$A,DATE(MAX(YEAR($B$3:$B$20)),12,31)))>=$G3)
     *(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,MIN($B$3:$B$20)):INDEX($A:$A,DATE(MAX(YEAR($B$3:$B$20)),12,31)))<=EOMONTH($G3,0)),
      INDEX(C$3:C$20,N(IF({1},MATCH(ROW(INDEX($A:$A,MIN($B$3:$B$20)):INDEX($A:$A,DATE(MAX(YEAR($B$3:$B$20)),12,31))),$B$3:$B$20))))
     )
)
```

It's basically the same as using a helper column to generate a date for each day across the whole range, except that it's generated inside the formula by the ROW(INDEX...)) statements.

Must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch Tom! I tried copying the second formula and entered as CSE, however, the entire output was for [March 1990](https://imgur.com/a/LEg2cop) (all output was 22). Any idea what I could have done wrong?

Comment: No probs. I'm wondering if what you did was to highlight the whole range before entering the formula? That would give you the same thing all the way down. You just need to CSE the formula into the first cell (X3 I think), then drag it to the other cells in the same column. I need to put some dollar signs into the formula actually so you can drag it across, so will tidy my answer up a bit shortly, but that won't affect the present issue.

Comment: Hey Tom, that helped clear it up perfectly. I added the $ signs myself and it looks all good. Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

See if this works for you.  Paste the below code into a new module in VBA ...

```
Public Function CalculateAveragePrice(ByVal strItemNo As String, ByVal dtMonth As Date, ByVal rngData As Range) As Variant
    Dim lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long, lngItemCol As Long, i As Long, bFoundTop As Boolean, lngYear As Long
    Dim dtThisDate As Date, dtComparisonDate As Date, arrDays() As Double, dtNextDate As Date, lngMonth As Long
    Dim lngBottomRow As Long, lngTopRow As Long, lngDaysInMonth As Long, dblCurrentPrice As Double

    ' Initialise the array with something.
    ReDim arrDays(0)

    lngMonth = Month(dtMonth)
    lngYear = Year(dtMonth)

    With rngData
        ' Find the header column for the item
        For lngItemCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
            If .Cells(1, lngItemCol) = strItemNo Then Exit For
        Next

        For i = 1 To 2
            If i = 1 Then
                dtComparisonDate = DateSerial(Year(dtMonth), Month(dtMonth), 1)
            Else
                dtComparisonDate = DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("m", 1, dtMonth))
                lngDaysInMonth = Day(dtComparisonDate)
                ReDim Preserve arrDays(lngDaysInMonth)
            End If

            For lngRow = 2 To .Rows.Count
                dtThisDate = .Cells(lngRow, 1)

                If i = 1 Then
                    If dtThisDate < dtComparisonDate Then lngBottomRow = lngRow
                Else
                    If dtThisDate > dtComparisonDate And Not bFoundTop Then
                        lngTopRow = lngRow
                        bFoundTop = True
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next

        If lngTopRow = 0 Then lngTopRow = .Rows.Count
        If lngBottomRow = 0 Then lngBottomRow = 2

        For i = 1 To UBound(arrDays)
            For lngRow = lngTopRow To lngBottomRow Step -1
                dtThisDate = .Cells(lngRow, 1)
                dblCurrentPrice = .Cells(lngRow, lngItemCol)

                If dtThisDate <= DateSerial(lngYear, lngMonth, i) Then
                    arrDays(i) = dblCurrentPrice + arrDays(i - 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next

        If UBound(arrDays) > 0 Then CalculateAveragePrice = arrDays(UBound(arrDays)) / UBound(arrDays)
    End With
End Function
```

... and then setup your formula to look like the below ...

[image: Formula Setup]

The code will also work for dates well outside the range of given prices. That may not be important for you but just something to note.

There's probably a more elegant way but it works for me and I trust it will work for you too.

See how it goes.

Comment: Hi Skin, first of all much appreciated for the effort! However, I've tried adding the VBA module but when I use the CalculateAveragePrice formula I get a [#NAME](https://imgur.com/a/CFqCrfJ) error. I'm not too familiar with VBA, any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: Okay, sorry I figured the #NAME error above!.

However the [output values seem wrong](https://imgur.com/a/WMkFekx). Could it be a date formatting issue?

Comment: @Brian wow, that’s unexpected. Can you put the worksheet somewhere so I can get it? If it’s not sensitive of course. OneDrive? DropBox?

Comment: @Brian must be something to do with dates because I just replicated the top few dates, etc. and I got a correct result.  We'll be able to work through it if I can get a copy of your workbook.  If I get it and it works for me straight up then it will be localisation ... which, of course, is a pain in the arse.

Comment: @Brian, I just noticed one line of code that may have cause the issue.  Can you copy the code in the answer and try again?

Comment: Hi, just managed to see this. Yes, it looks like that line of code you fixed did the trick! That is great. Thank you so much

Comment: @Brian no worries man, feel free to flag it as the answer. This one wasn’t as straight forward as some answers I’ve given so would appreciate the reputation.  :-)

Comment: Oh hold on. It looks like the change fixed some of the columns, but other columns like those for HFO 800 remain an issue. For example August 1990 returns a flat 5 instead of 5.106. [Try taking a look at the file here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uzzp1JMVx8NRgzK-HH9nsjU_eDJbQlD3/view?usp=sharing) (there are two weighted average sections as i've been trying out both solutions for this question)

Comment: @Brian ... bugger!  Right'o, will take a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot Skin, I am glad to know there's a VBA solution, but i'll be going ahead with the formula answer as its slightly more portable across workbooks. I wish there was a way to upvote both answers. 

Do feel free to post a fixed VBA code if you get to sort it out though, it could help others down the road.

Comment: @Brian yeah, solid idea. Glad you got your answer.

Comment: Fixed it anyway just in case some poor sucker is wanting a solution in VBA.  I had declared the price array as long when it needed to be a double.  Keen to see if it works for yo across the board now but don't bust your gut if you're now done with all of this.

Comment: Yes, it works now, just tried it. Shoutout to you for staying this through. Again, wish I could double vote the right answer

Comment: @Brian mate, all good. You gotta go with what’s right for you. It was a nice little challenge for me anyway.